# SHA1 implementation differs from builtin SHA1

Tags: python, hash, sha1

I'm trying to reimplement the SHA1 algorithm in python, but the result of my function differs from the one in builtin hashlib, at first I thought the problem was in my rotate function, but after fixing it, there is still a difference in the outputs, here is my code:

```py
from hashlib import sha1 as builtin_sha1

def rotl32(value: int, count: int) -> int:
  return ((value << count) | (value >> (32 - count))) & 0xffffffff


def default_sha1(data: bytes) -> bytes:
  return builtin_sha1(data).digest()


def sha1(data: bytes) -> bytes:
  # initialize variables
  h0 = 0x67452301
  h1 = 0xefcdab89
  h2 = 0x98badcfe
  h3 = 0x10325476
  h4 = 0xc3d2e1f0

  msg_len = len(data)

  # append 0x80
  data += b"\x80"

  # append 0x00 until msg_len % 64 == 56
  data += b"\x00" * ((56 - msg_len % 64) % 64)

  # append bit length as 64-bit big-endian integer
  data += (msg_len * 8).to_bytes(8, "big")

  # get the new length (now a multiple of 64)
  msg_len = len(data)

  for i in range(0, msg_len, 64):
    # for each chunk of 64 bytes

    # break the chunk into sixteen 32-bit big-endian words
    words = [int.from_bytes(data[i + j:i + j + 4], "big")
             for j in range(0, 64, 4)]

    # extend the sixteen 32-bit words into eighty 32-bit words
    for j in range(16, 80):
      words.append(
        rotl32((words[j - 3] ^ words[j - 8] ^ words[j - 14] ^ words[j - 16]), 1)
      )

    # initialize hash value for this chunk
    a = h0
    b = h1
    c = h2
    d = h3
    e = h4

    for j in range(80):
      if 0 <= j <= 19:
        f = (b & c) | ((~b) & d)
        k = 0x5a827999
      elif 20 <= j <= 39:
        f = b ^ c ^ d
        k = 0x6ed9eba1
      elif 40 <= j <= 59:
        f = (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d)
        k = 0x8f1bbcdc
      else:  # 60 <= j <= 79:
        f = b ^ c ^ d
        k = 0xca62c1d6

      temp = (rotl32(a, 5) + f + e + k + words[j]) & 0xffffffff
      e = d
      d = c
      c = rotl32(b, 30)
      b = a
      a = temp

    # add this chunk's hash to result so far
    h0 = (h0 + a) & 0xffffffff
    h1 = (h1 + b) & 0xffffffff
    h2 = (h2 + c) & 0xffffffff
    h3 = (h3 + d) & 0xffffffff
    h4 = (h4 + e) & 0xffffffff

  # produce the final hash value
  return ((h0 << 128) | (h1 << 96) | (h2 << 64) | (h3 << 32) | h4).to_bytes(20, "big")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  assert(sha1(b"hello") == default_sha1(b"hello")) # diff
```

Maybe it's an endianness problem, but I use big endian everywhere, I used as reference the pseudo code on wikipedia [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

EDIT: I was appending the byte length of the message instead of the bit length, now the code is corrected and appends the bit length but it still differs from the builtin implementation

Comment: What are the results of your attempts to debug the problem? Where to the observations diverge from the expectations?

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know how to debug the problem since I can't manage to access to the standard implementation code, that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, the issue was in the formula to calculate the padding, instead of

```
data += b"\x00" * ((56 - msg_len % 64) % 64)
```

it should be

```
data += b"\x00" * ((56 - (msg_len + 1) % 64) % 64)
```

Since I calculated `len(msg)` before appending `0x80`, I needed to add `1` to `msg_len` to get the actual length.